# Using the same form multiple times over a single column in a template Django

Tags: html, django, forms, http, django-forms

I gotta a school management web app. In my app teachers can create exams and then add grades to that. I've created a separate model for grades. This is my models right now:

```
class Grade(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(
        Student, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name="grade_user",
    )
    subject = models.ForeignKey(
        Subject, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name="grade_subject",
    )
    grade = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)


class Exam(models.Model):
    ...

    grades = models.ManyToManyField(
        Grade, 
        related_name="exam_grades",
        blank=True,
    )
```

Now I've created a form like following:

[image]

Teachers fill the fields and then using a single button this should be submitted. But the problem is that I don't know how to implement such implementation. I read somethings about formsets but I want the fields to be in a single column.
Is there any way to get this done?

Comment: This is usually done with *formsets*: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: Hello @WillemVanOnsem please help me on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69418183/how-to-change-referral-of-user-if-user-is-inactive-in-django